# How to reconcile waiver and liability terms of a contract?

Tags: contract-law

If a contract contains both of the following clauses, how do they not contradict each other?

> 24.3  Each party agrees that it shall have no right or remedy (other than for breach of contract) in respect of any statement,
>   representation, assurance or warranty (whether made negligently or
>   innocently) other than as expressly set out in this Agreement.
>
> 24.4  Neither party shall have any liability to the other party, whether in contract, tort (including negligence), breach of statutory
>   duty, or otherwise, for any loss of profit, or for any indirect or
>   consequential loss arising under or in connection with this Agreement.

Answer (score 2):

24.3 prohibits lawsuits not based upon a contract theory.

24.3 prohibits certain kinds of damages from being awarded in an allowed lawsuit (i.e. "loss of profit . . . indirect or consequential loss").

Thus, direct damages are allowed (e.g. a suit for refund of the purchase price if the item purchased doesn't work), but not indirect damages (e.g. loss of business due to the fact that the item purchased doesn't work).